# How do I calculate the distance between source and destination latitude longitude points in aws lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the source Lat Long points and destination Lat Long points in a dynamodb table. I need to take those points from the table and calculate the distance between them in a lambda function.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not understanding how to implement haversine formula in lambda function.

Comment: See if this helps,https://read.acloud.guru/location-based-search-results-with-dynamodb-and-geohash-267727e5d54f

Answer (score 0):

This code in javascript calculates distances between the two lat, longs – using the ‘Haversine’ formula.

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```